# How to create a general action that changes tabs in GUI?

Tags: java, swing, action

I have several actionListeners throughout my code for when I push a button, it changes tabs between the ones I have.
However, I would like to create a general action that depending on which button was pressed (through an int), it changed to a different tab. This is the current actionListener I have.

```
    JButton btnSaveAddESS = new JButton("Save");
    btnSaveAddESS.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            tabbedBackground.setSelectedIndex(0);
            tabbedBackground.setEnabledAt(1, false);    
        }
    });
```

With this, I would like to create a general action, however , while creating the action as a different class, I am not able to access the TabbedPane (tabbedBackground) component.

How can I implement this, avoiding actionListeners?

Thanks,
Nhekas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
changeTab(int i){
 tabbedBackground.setSelectedIndex(i);
 tabbedBackground.setEnabledAt(i, false); 
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
int i = Integer.parseInt(Jbutton.getText());
changeTab(int i); 
        }
```

what you need is actually a method which handles the operation pass an int to the method changetab and the method will change the selectedTab

Comment: thanks for the reply, Now, I just call that function within different action listeners, right?

However, is it possble to avoid the actionListerners completely?

Comment: its a method you can call it from anywhere. what you need to worry about is passing a correct int value otherwise you may end up in errors.